# Mysql left join very slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a left join:

```
$query = "SELECT a.`id`, a.`documenttitle`, a.`committee`, a.`issuedate`, b.`tagname`
   FROM `#__document_management_documents` AS a 
   LEFT JOIN `#__document_managment_tags` AS b 
   ON a.id = b.documentid 
   ".$tagexplode."
   ".$issueDateText."
   AND a.committee in (".$committeeQueryTextExplode.")
   AND a.documenttitle LIKE '".$documentNameFilter."%'
   GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY a.documenttitle ASC

  ";
```

It's really slow abaout 7 seconds on 4000 records

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong

```
SELECT a.`id`, a.`documenttitle`, a.`committee`, a.`issuedate`, b.`tagname` 
FROM `w4c_document_management_documents` AS a 
LEFT JOIN `document_managment_tags` AS b 
ON a.id = b.documentid WHERE a.issuedate >= '' 
AND a.committee in ('1','8','9','10','11','12','13','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47') 
AND a.documenttitle LIKE '%' GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY a.documenttitle ASC
```

Comment: Can you show the query after the PHP values have been interpolated?

Comment: if you have a lot of records in table a, it might be the like operator in the where clause that's slowing it down. Consider using a full text index and match(...) against()

Comment: Can you execute and show us the result of : `SHOW INDEX FROM __document_management_documents; SHOW INDEX FROM __document_managment_tags;`

Comment: You may need to add indexes to optimize slow queries.  For instance, if documentid is not an index in table b, you may be able to optimize table b by adding that column as an index.

Comment: the index result was:
w4c_document_management_documents  0  PRIMARY  1  id  A  860  NULL NULL  BTREE

Comment: `AND a.documenttitle LIKE '%'`??? `$documentNameFilter` seems to be empty.

Comment: the document filter line is actually AND a.documenttitle LIKE '".$documentNameFilter."%' so it allows for the user to add text for searching if needed

Comment: Could you show the output of an EXPLAIN?

Comment: okay so I think I've got is solved - thanks for all the help.  I moved the and in a.committee into the where clause and that made it go at the expected speed

Answer (score 0):

I would put an index on a.committee, and full text index the doctitle col. The IN and LIKE are immediate flags to me. Issue date should also have an index because you are >= it

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following commands in a MySQL client:

```
show index from #__document_management_documents;
show index from #_document_management_tags;
```

Check to see if there are keys/indexes on the `id` and `documentid` fields from the respective tables. If there aren't, MySQL will be doing a full table scan to lookup the values. Creating indexes on these fields makes the search time logarithmic, because it sorts them in a binary tree which is stored in the index file. Even better is to use primary keys (if possible), because that way the row data is stored in the leaf, which saves MySQL another I/O operation to lookup the data.

It could also simply be that the IN and >= operators have bad performance, in which case you might have to rewrite your queries or redesign your tables.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, try to find if your columns have index. You can even do "EXPLAIN" command in your MySQL client at the start of your query to see if the query is actually using indexes. You will see in the 'key' columns and 'Extra' column. Get more information [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information)

This will help you optimize your query. Also group by causes using temporary and filesort which causes MySQL to create a temporary table and going through each rows. If you could use PHP to group by it would be faster.